# Fractal Koch Curve

Tags: python

My project that involves antenna design, in which Python generates the .nec file that allows me to model fractal antennas in the software and optimize them for the best performance. The program is intended to work with multiple fractal antennas, including all of the following:

- Koch Curve
- Hilbert Curve
- Koch Snowflake

Don't worry, this isn't a homework assignment. I am giving a speech on Fractal Antennas and wanted to automate the design process, otherwise it is tedious.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with calculating the center point of the Koch Curve. Here is an image of what it looks like in software; note that I still geometry bugs that need to be solved.

[image: Koch Fractal in 4NEC2]

[Here](https://github.com/ElectroNerd/Fractal/blob/master/NEC%20Files/KochCurve.nec) are the coordinates of the resulting Python script using a iteration level of 3 and segment size of 0.305m.

The Python scripts that is currently being subjugated to my madness are pointed out below:

[.NEC File](https://github.com/ElectroNerd/Fractal/blob/master/NEC%20Files/KochCurve.nec)

[Coordinates](http://codepad.org/9ld6nivu)

[4NEC2_Generator.py Code](https://github.com/ElectroNerd/Fractal/blob/master/4NEC2/4NEC2_Generator.py)

[Complete Project](https://github.com/ElectroNerd/Fractal)

As you will  notice in the image depiction of the Koch Curve, it is off center by a tiny amount. My equation to find the complete length is this:

[image: Center Point Equation]

Where:

```
 l = total side-length (referenced from the bottom) of the Koch Curve
 s = segment size (my segment size was 0.305m, they should all be equal)
 n = number of iterations
```

Does anyone know why I'm not getting the center?

Thanks,

Austin

Comment: Is one side of it supposed to be longer than the other?

Comment: No, they should be equal length. This antenna is a dipole, so I'm trying to split it symmetrically and have the feed line at the very tip of the center triangle. I added the actual coordinates generated from Python to give you all a better idea of what the output is.

Comment: I took a look at your code, are you sure all that lines of code are necessary, or at least are necessary to solve the asymmetry problem? Could you shrink your code and paste it directly on the question?

Comment: I looked a bit more, and your code is very convoluted (speghetti-code), it is not clear what does what, and there seems to be a lot of hardcoded numbers that are meaningless to anyone outside the problem domain.

Comment: Wouldn't the center be the center of the original line that the curve is based off of?

Comment: @Dave Newton: yes, I also think so, but it is hard to find it in the linked code, at least to me.

Comment: How/where are you rounding? You're not, in the vowel-deprived `hilbertCntrPnt`. Also, that method doesn't seem to follow your formula, if I'm looking at the right one.

Comment: In hilbertCntrPnt (I will change that to hilbertCenterPoint), I ran it in the command line and it works fine.

Comment: I don't want to round, it should be as precise as possible! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you should try to reimplement your iterative calculation being more canonical.

An answer to a request for a good Koch Curve algorithm in Python is here:

[Implementing the Koch Curve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932222/implementing-the-koch-curve/932498#932498)

(and also the original code in the question could help you a lot)

EDIT:
I created a script which uses code from the provided link, plus Cairo and Python Image Library (PIL) to render an image. Hope it helps:

```
#!/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import math

angles = [math.radians(60*x) for x in range(6)]
sines = [math.sin(x) for x in angles]
cosin = [math.cos(x) for x in angles]

def L(angle, coords, jump):
    return (angle + 1) % 6
def R(angle, coords, jump):
    return (angle + 4) % 6
def F(angle, coords, jump):
    coords.append(
        (coords[-1][0] + jump * cosin[angle],
         coords[-1][1] + jump * sines[angle]))
    return angle

decode = dict(L=L, R=R, F=F)

def koch(steps, length=200, startPos=(0,0)):
    pathcodes="F"
    for i in xrange(steps):
        pathcodes = pathcodes.replace("F", "FLFRFLF")

    jump = float(length) / (3 ** steps)
    coords = [startPos]
    angle = 0

    for move in pathcodes:
        angle = decode[move](angle, coords, jump)

    return coords


TOTALWIDTH = 1000

points = koch(3,TOTALWIDTH,(-TOTALWIDTH/2,0))
print points


# optional part, shows an image with Y axis(good for debugging)
import cairo, Image

width = TOTALWIDTH
height = int(TOTALWIDTH*0.32)
surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
cr = cairo.Context(surface)
cr.set_source_rgb(1,1,1)
cr.rectangle(0, 0, width, height)
cr.fill()
cr.translate(width*0.5, height*0.95)
cr.scale(1, -1)

# red Y axis:
cr.set_source_rgb(1,0,0)
cr.move_to(0,0)
cr.line_to(0,300)
cr.stroke()

cr.set_source_rgb(0,0,0)
cr.set_line_width(0.5)
cr.move_to(*points[0])
for n in range(len(points)):
    cr.line_to(*points[n])
cr.stroke()

im = Image.frombuffer("RGBA", (width, height), surface.get_data(), "raw", "BGRA", 0,1)
im.show()
```

Comment: That definitely helped, I am going to implement that method into my code. Stay tuned!

Comment: I didn't considered you have a fixed segment-length, as opposed to the antenna's overall width, but it should be simple to find a correlation between them and to get width from steps and segment-length

Comment: Well that worked, I added it to my project code on Git, but do you think I should eventually get this working with my UndrawnTurtle() class?

Comment: Honestly, I would remove every Turtle stuff from the project at all. Indeed, what you want is an ordered list of point coordinates do create a polyline, and that is what the provided code returns. From such list, you can easily get an output in .NEC format, or whatever other text format you want (XML, CSV, JSON, Matlab, etc.), be it using some library or directly from Python with string formatting.

Comment: Hmmm...yeah, but what about a Koch snowflake? And the Hilbert Curve? Is there other Python code that has this same approach, but for the Koch Snowflake and Hilbert Curve?

Comment: Well, becoming a pragmatic programmer involves adapting the general parts of the codes that inspire you, and create your own particular parts to solve your particular needs. Also, take a look at the link provided, I will post an answer which bypasses the turtle stuff at all.

Comment: I bypass Turtle, take a look at my UndrawnTurtle() class. It is nothing to do with Turtle and everything to do with the coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the recursion to compute the new length of a side:

```
def kochCurve(level, lengthSide):

    if(level == 0):
        ut.fd(lengthSide)
    else:
        newLengthSide = level/3.0     ## <-- Wrong.
        newLevel = level - 1

        kochCurve(newLevel, newLengthSide)
        ut.lt(60)
        kochCurve(newLevel, newLengthSide)
        ut.rt(120)
        kochCurve(newLevel, newLengthSide)
        ut.lt(60)
        kochCurve(newLevel, newLengthSide)
```

You compute the newLengthSide without any reference to the current length side.  The line should be this:

```
        newLengthSide = lengthSide / 3.0
```

The reason your segments are 0.33333 is because you ignore the .305 passed in and start with 1/3.0.

I'm not sure exactly what the passed in value is supposed to represent, so this may not be the right new line to use, but this is why your segments are the wrong length.

Comment: I was oblivious to that! I changed it and it made the antenna quite smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to use the traditional code that I had, but that was only due to one preliminary factor: the fact that my kochCurve() code is based off of the total length underneath the Koch Curve, whereas before, I traditionally thought it determined the individual segment length. Thus, the center point was easily determined.

Here are images that my resulting script procured:

[image: Main Panel]

[image: 2D Radiation Slice]

[image: 3D Radiation Pattern]

I appreciate the help!